# Calling inherited method confusion

Tags: php

Can someone explain me why i'm getting the results as below? (look at the comments).

```
class A {
    public function foo() {         // foo from B
    //private function foo() {      // foo from A
        echo "foo from A</br>";
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo() {
        echo "foo from B</br>";
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
```

Shouldn't i always get "foo from B" while "this" pointing to class B object?

Comment: What results do you get? When I run the script here the output is `foo from B</br>` as expected.

Comment: If the 'foo()` function was made available to sub classes via 'protected' or 'public' qualifiers then it works as you expect. However, it would be made clear in the interface or abstract class. In the previous case where `foo()` was `private` then it would not be mentioned anywhere available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Because **$this** is using late binding method,

read official documentation about bindings (static or non-static does not matter)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: Yes I've read official documentation thousand times but i can't understand theirs explanation. So can You explain me the case in Yours way?

Comment: late binding means late (last) extended class

Comment: So late (last) extended class is B?

Comment: So $this in test method reefers to B class and that's why the result is "foo from B"?